# Access denied for user 'user1'@'localhost' goddady

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

does anybody know in which table godaddy store the users  table ?
I have a database created using database wizard and I have added a user using the mysql database wizard to the database. But I still get the error;

> Connection failed: Access denied for user 'user1'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I tried this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user1'@'%'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

But I keep getting;

> 1045 - Access denied for user 'cpses_odldzcvpqv'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

It must have something to do with the  USER_PRIVILEGES table in information_shema. when I type

```
SELECT * FROM `USER_PRIVILEGES`
```

IS_GRANTABLE is set to NO.

[image]

Comment: As its a shared MySQL Server between you and 100's of other sites, I would be V.V.V Amazed if you can get access to the user table

Comment: main goal is to grant access to all privileges for user1 , if I cannot get access to the users table , that would be fine.

Comment: Is this a Shared Hosting package or did you buy the whole server

Comment: Shared Hosting package

Comment: _It must have something to do with the USER_PRIVILEGES_ YES You are NOT the administrator (root) on this instance of MySQL. You and 100 other people are placing databases on this instance. You can only use the front end provided to create users on the instance.

Answer (score 0):

On unix based systems, mysql treats localhost and tcp/ip separately. If you wish to give access to localhost, you must also give an explicit permission to `localhost` along with `%`.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user1'@'localhost' identified by '<password>';
```

or you can connect via `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost. That'll work.

```
mysql -u user1 -p<password> --host 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: I tried this , but still getting error: #1045 - Access denied for user 'cpses_odefnnv5g4'@'localhost' (using password: YES)